# How to stop writing nesting code in node-mysql ( node.js, express, mysql )

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

Each time I throw a query, the nest depth increase by one, just like the code below. If I knew how to define a query as a function not in the action, the readability of my code would increase.

```
exports.getAll = function (req, res) {

    client.query('SELECT * FROM tag', function (err, result, fields) {
        client.destroy();

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        var tag = result[0].tag;

        client.query('SELECT COUNT(follow_id) AS following_tag_num FROM follow WHERE user_id = ?', [req.session.user.user_id], function (err, result, fields) {
            client.destroy();

            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            res.render('hoge', {
                title: 'Welcome to Hoge',
                userInfo: req.session.user,
                tag: tag,
                following_tag_num: result[0].following_tag_num
            });
        });

    });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the handler a named function:

```
client.query(
  'SELECT COUNT(follow_id) AS following_tag_num FROM follow WHERE user_id = ?',
  [req.session.user.user_id],
  handleResult
);

function handleResult(err, result, fields) {
  client.destroy();

  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  res.render('hoge', {
    title            : 'Welcome to Hoge',
    userInfo         : req.session.user,
    tag              : tag,
    following_tag_num: result[0].following_tag_num
  });
}
```

Comment: Is `client` really in scope in the callback?

Comment: @sarnold: Yes, it will be in the closure for the function.

Comment: thanks! but in that case wont the flow of my code jump each time when i throw a query?
i want the flow of my code stay in the action. so i need a solution which i can call the client.query as a defined function in my action.
so that i can keep writing code in my action by the result of that function.

Comment: You won't be able to call `query()` and then use the results inside your action, because the results are always passed to the callback. That's part of the asynchronous nature of Javascript/Node.

Comment: Actually there are some good flow control modules available via `npm` that should help. I added another answer about one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You might look into several node flow control modules that are available to help curb the nesting. I like one called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It provides a variety of ways to de-nest your nested code.

```
var async = require('async');
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        client.query(sql, callback);
    },
    function(results, callback) {
        // do something with results, then call callback
    }],
    function(err, data) {
        // if any errors occur above, err is not null
        // otherwise 'data' is whatever got passed to the last callback
    });
```

`async.waterfall` takes a list of functions, and passes the results of each one on to the next, finally calling the second parameter, another function, with the final result. Results are passed not by returning them, but by a callback function. `async` also supports running several functions in parallel, in series, and a variety of different common patterns used in node.